# Is Wikipedia's formal definition of NP correct?

Tags: complexity-theory, terminology, np

[Wikipedia's formal definition of NP based on deterministic verifiers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP_%28complexity%29#Formal_definition) states:

> A language L is in NP if and only if there exist polynomials p and q,
>   and a deterministic Turing machine M, such that
>
> - For all x and y, the machine M runs in time p(|x|) on input (x,y)
> - For all x in L, there exists a string y of length q(|x|) such that M(x,y) = 1
> - For all x not in L and all strings y of length q(|x|), M(x,y) = 0

I'm not an expert in the field but the first bullet point leads me to think that M must run in time p(|x|) regardless of the size of y, which doesn't seem to be true, at least if M gets to read y completely. What if |y| > p(|x|)?

Is the first bullet point of the definition correct? Shouldn't it be

> For all x and y, the machine M runs in time p(|x|+|y|) on input (x,y)

Can you point me to an authoritative source with the original definition of NP based on deterministic verifiers?

Comment: I think that is the accepted standard. When the witness is too long, the TM just doesn't read/use it all.

Comment: A definition can be (un)useful or (in)consistent with other definitions, but it's never correct or wrong.

Answer (score 2):

I am currently reading "Introduction to the Theory of Computation" by Sipser and think that it is a great introduction to complexity (as well as automata and computability). Here are his definitions of **Verifier** and **NP**:

> **Definition 7.18**: A **verifier** for a language $A$ is an algorithm $V$, where $A = \{ w \mid V \text{ accepts } \langle w, c \rangle \text{ for some string } c \}.$ We measure the time of a verifier only in terms of the length
> of $w$, so a polynomial time verifier runs in polynomial time in the
> length of $w$. A language $A$ is polynomially verifiable if it has a
> polynomial time verifier. (Sipser, 293)
>
> **Definition 7.19**: **NP** is the class of languages that have polynomial time verifiers. (Sipser, 294)

Translating the wiki definition into the above, $A = L$, $V = M$, $w = x$, and $c = y$. It seems that the first condition of the wiki definition is correct, and this may make more sense given the alternative definition of NP. A language $L$ is in NP if there exists a non-deterministic TM $N$ that decides $L$ in non-deterministic polynomial time $NTIME(n^k)$. Here, the running time of $N$ is measured in terms of its input size $n = |w| = |x|$.

However, I have not seen nor am I familiar with the second condition, but that seems to set some upper bound on the length of $y$ so that $|y|$ is a polynomial in $|x|$, which should answer your question about if $|y| > p(|x|)$. I figure the second condition is to protect against padding arguments. At any rate, if $p(|x|) < q(|x|)$, then $p(|x|) < |y| < q(|x|)$, so $|y|$ is still a polynomial in $|x|$.

Comment: I also want to point out that the second condition in the wiki may not be necessary. If $M$ does not reject inputs $y$ where $|y| \geq$, say $2^{O(|x|)}$, then $M$ is not a polynomial time verifier of $L$. This is obvious when the language is non-trivial, like $L = \{ \langle G, k \rangle \mid G \text{ has a clique of size at least } k \}$. If $|y| > |\langle G, k \rangle|$, then $y$ is obviously not a solution, so any polynomial-time verifier $M$ must reject such instances. Someone please correct me if I am wrong.